# Send a file from facebook messenger (api.ai)

Tags: facebook-messenger-bot

I'm creating a bot for facebook messenger with api.ai,in the doc says that i must to write the following code on the 'custom payload' option:

```
"message":{
    "attachment":{
      "type":"file",
      "payload":{
        "url":"https://petersapparel.com/bin/receipt.pdf"
      }
    }
}
```

but it doesnt work, someone know if I missed something? The url that I use works correctly.

Comment: 2 things to consider. First is to use upload file or linking a url here my example 
 https://gist.github.com/fatfingers/d7c090068a68b8b7238bd85374b6e34c  .Second is to whitelist your domain  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/messenger-profile/domain-whitelisting

Comment: thanks kar, we need to whitelist the domain for each connection? (when I send something to my domain and when I receive something)

Comment: You only need to whitelist your server domain for every pages linked to your bot using page token. Eg: `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "whitelisted_domains":[
    "https://sub1.mysite.com", "https://sub2.mysite.com"
  ]
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the sample in dev docs?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/file-attachment

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "recipient":{
    "id":"USER_ID"
  },
  "message":{
    "attachment":{
      "type":"file",
      "payload":{
        "url":"https://petersapparel.com/bin/receipt.pdf"
      }
    }
  }
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

Comment: Yes, I tried the sample and doesn't work, and I tried with my PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN too, should I wrote all this sample in the Sample Payload text boxt ? I've seen the same sample with and without the first 3 lines.

Comment: I tried sending image to myself worked: 
     curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
      "recipient":{
        "id":"1471306002939594"
      },
      "message":{
        "attachment":{
          "type":"image",
          "payload":{
            "url":"https://img1.wsimg.com/pc/img/1/trademark/nonregistered/godaddy-logo.png"
          }
        }
      }
    }' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=$PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"
    {"recipient_id":"1471306002939594","message_id":"mid.$cAAEenRz66V1jT8G3cldHnxuo_N2w"}